# Can we resolve tension force into components for net force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

When solving certain questions , I noticed that in some places we take component of gravity along the string while in others, we take component of tension along gravity, I think that both of these methods should give the same result but they dont. Some people also told me that assume you have a car being pulled by two ropes, will acceleration be double? But why is tension force so special? What am i doing wrong by taking component of tension along an other force? Thanks in advance.+

Comment: Without explicit examples, it is impossible to understand what you are puzzled about.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XmBZymk       sort of like in this one

Comment: What is $u$ in your diagram?  You have it pointing in three different directions.

Comment: @garyp It is the velocity with which string is being pulled.

Comment: This may also help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/648788/305718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the distance between the pulleys is $2x$ and the weight is a distance $y$ below the pulleys then the distance $z$ from either pulley satisfies

$z^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Differentiating and using the fact that $x$ is constant gives

$\displaystyle 2z \frac {dz}{dt} = 2y \frac{dy}{dt}
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {dy}{dt} = \frac z y \frac {dz}{dt} = \sec \theta \frac {dz}{dt}$

Your method assumes that $y = z \cos \theta$ implies $\frac {dy}{dt} = \frac {dz}{dt}\cos \theta$ but this would only be true if $\theta$ were constant, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The force which a tension exerts on an object is a vector like any other force and can be broken into components.  If you are getting a conflict, you are probably doing something wrong. (I'm not seeing a diagram.)